# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' in a program that was executing well before

Tags: python, string, int, operands

while doing this

```
year = 2019
tariq1 = year+'-01-01'
tariq2 = year+'-12-31'
while year > 2015:
    for stock in string:
        max=quandl.get(stock, start_date=tariq1, end_date=tariq2)
        max
    year = year - 1
```

getting an error in the line

```
tariq =year+'-01-01'
```

_--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

```
     1 year = 2019
----> 2 tariq1 = year+'-01-01'
      3 tariq2 = year+'-12-31'
      4 while year > 2015:
      5     for stock in string:_
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

where quandl.get returns a dataframe to max. I am also getting same error for year in another code. I did not encounter this before in numerous execution for the same code. Just getting this now. any help would be welcome. thanks

Comment: `year` is an integer. You can't concatenate integers and strings. We don't know what your code was like before, but you certainly weren't using *this* code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `year` to a string before concatenating it.

```
year = 2019
tariq1 = str(year)+'-01-01'
tariq2 = str(year)+'-12-31'
while year > 2015:
    for stock in string:
        max=quandl.get(stock, start_date=tariq1, end_date=tariq2)
        max
    year = year - 1
```

On a side note, you probably also want to update the values of `tariq1` and `tariq2` inside of the loop, rather than before it:

```
year = 2019
while year > 2015:
    tariq1 = str(year)+'-01-01'
    tariq2 = str(year)+'-12-31'
    for stock in string:
        max=quandl.get(stock, start_date=tariq1, end_date=tariq2)
        max
    year = year - 1
```